# text file each line to command in bash

Tags: python, arrays, bash, text

okay so I have a pythonscript that takes an argument like so

```
& ./myscript.py argumentishere
```

what u want to do is read a text file that has multipule lines of text and for each line execute my command like so

```
& ./myscript.py line1
& ./myscript.py line2
& ./myscript.py line3
ect.ect.ect
```

how can I achieve this in a bash script

Comment: Does your Python scripte accept multiple arguments or does it expect the entire line as a single argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can achieve this with a bash script, probably the easier way is to use the `xargs` utility.

```
xargs -L 1 ./myscript.py <inputfile
```

The bash way would be:

```
while read line
do
    ./myscript $line
done <inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat input | while read line
do
    ./myscript.py $line
done
```

you also need add `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the head of myscript.py and chmod executable properity to myscript.py

Comment: Oh dear, this is one of the worst ways to parse a file line by line in bash. (An even worse one is to use `for`).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Why is this way so bad?

Comment: @CharlesBailey Because this executes the `while` loop in a subshell, and uses an unnecessary external `cat`. The bash way is: `while read; do ...; done < file` as shown in the other answers. (NB. the question _is_ tagged [tag:bash]).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Unless the python script is trivial and the input consists of very few lines, I wouldn't have thought either of those factors would have much impact, to be fair.

Comment: @CharlesBailey It's not a matter of having impact... it's just a matter of _knowing_ how to do things properly so that each time you do them, you do them right without even thinking. The problem with doing things without caring, is that this snippet will soon grow longer, and at some point there will be some variables defined in the `while` loop, and you'll observe strange results (because this loop is in a subshell)... oh dear, if only you had done it properly from the beginning. You like programming as I've noticed on your profile, so you should at least understand a little bit what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd modify the python script to take a filename as argument and do what I want with each line.

```
import sys
file = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in file:
    #do your thing here
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ./myscript.py "$line"
done < file
```