# changing proxy for each command executed

Tags: python, arrays, bash, proxy

okay so I am using this bash  script

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
./script.py "$line"
done < /root/Desktop/1.txt >> /root/Desktop/2.txt
```

what this does is obviously add each lines contents to the .py script as argument and executes it how can I make my script change the ip every time 3 lines are check can anyone help

so every time it check or line or 3 it will change the proxy on backtrack to the next unused proxy out of proxy.txt

Comment: Short answer: you can't with this method. Instead use the other methods provided in the answers, [for example this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741617/text-file-each-line-to-command-in-bash/19741659#19741659). `:)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the type to while IFS= read -r line; do
    ./script.py "$line"
done < /root/Desktop/1.txt >> /root/Desktop/2.txt